# Doctrine2 filter table in DB to make migrations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have been searching to make Doctrine ignoring all tables in a DB except for entities in my app. I was trying to do it with the schema_filter option in doctrine config, however i have a large amount of schemas (i'm using PostgreSQL) and tables in the DB that I don't need to watch with the App. So the easiest solution, IMO, would be to ignore all tables except for App\Entity\Custom folder (this is a shared DB with other apps / users who can create schemas / tables).

Also i'm using multiple connection, and I don't know how to solve my problem from now...

My config/packages/doctrine.yaml file :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: classic
        connections:
            classic:
                url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%"
                driver: "pdo_pgsql"
                server_version: "11.5"
                charset: "utf8"
            custom:
                url: "%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_CUSTOM)%"
                driver: "pdo_pgsql"
                server_version: "11.5"
                charset: "utf8"
                schema_filter: "How to filter all tables in DB except for entities table in App\Entity\Custom\* ?"
                
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: "classic"
        entity_managers:
            classic:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: "api"
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Classic"
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Classic'
                        alias: "Classic"
            custom:
                connection: "custom"
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Custom"
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Custom'
                        alias: "custom"
```

And I have also 2 migrations config file, cuz this would be greate to separate migrations / DB (I don't know if this is the best way to make it work) :

config/classic_migration.yaml :

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations\Classic': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Classic'
    enable_profiler: '%kernel.debug%'
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'public.migrations'
    em: classic
```

config/custom_migration.yaml:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        'DoctrineMigrations\Custom': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Custom'
    enable_profiler: '%kernel.debug%'
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'public.migrations'
    em: custom
```

Has someone any trick / advice to give me ?

Thank you.

Comment: A direct way to have doctrine ignore the undesired tables from one of the entity managers would be to create a separate connection + user with access to only the desired database(s) and/or tables the ORM manages. This is due to the assertion that Doctrine ORM is used to map and provision the database and tables, since developing the database and table schemas outside of the ORM is discouraged.  If manually issuing native queries to other tables that are not managed by the ORM, you would need a separate connection + user with access to support those special cases.

Comment: An indirect way of ignoring other tables that the ORM does not manage, is to create tables with a prefix for the table names that the `schema_filter` rule can explicitly manage. eg: `schema_filter: '~^(orm_)~'` for including only tables that begin with `orm_` There are several tutorials online on how to implement automatic table name prefixes in Doctrine.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, this is what i did. I didn't want to prefix all my tables but if their is no other solution I will content myself with this method.
Thanks again.